A problem that could use substitution or logs, not sure which works better
This is one of those brain teaser problems on instagram, and it starts here:
$$x^{x^2-2x+1} = 2x + 1$$
And we want to solve for x. My first instinct was to try this
$$\ln(x^{x^2-2x+1}) = \ln(2x + 1)\\
(x^2-2x+1)\ln(x) = \ln(2x + 1)\\
(x-1)^2\ln(x) = \ln(2x + 1)\\
(x-1)^2 = \frac{\ln(2x + 1)}{\ln(x)}$$
But at that point I wasn't sure what rules apply; I know that the natural log $\ln(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})=\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))$ but that doesn't work here. I could try
$$(x-1)^2 = \frac{\ln(2x + 1)}{\ln(x)}\\
(x-1)^2 = \frac{\ln(2(x + \frac{1}{2}))}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\ln(2)+\ln(x + \frac{1}{2})}{\ln(x)}$$
But htat seemed a dead end or over-complicated.
So another method was to say,
let $t= x-1$
So we get
$$x^{x^2-2x+1} = x^{(x-1)^2} = x^{t^2}\\
x^{t^2} = 2x + 1\\$$
And we can rewrite $2x+1$ as $2(x-1+1)+1$ which turns it into $2(t+1)+1$
$$x^{t^2}= 2(t+1) + 1\\
(t+1)^{t^2} = 2(t+1)+1\\$$
But I feel a bit stuck here. I could try natural logs again
$$(t^2)\ln(t+1) = \ln(2(t+1)+1)=\ln(2t+3)$$
But I feel that I have gone in circles, and that there is some very simple piece of algebra I am missing. Anyhow, any guidance would be appreciated. I do get the sense that the form squared binomials take is important here; I know that I could just say that $t^2 = 2$ and that can work, but I am trying to get the last step that gets me to that conclusion; I feel there is a step missing.

The equation may have been derived via the following. You can start with $x^2-2x=1,x=1+\sqrt 2$ and divide by $x$ or have $x$ to the power of the left and right hand sides. This gives $x^{x^2-2x}=x^1$ and $2+\frac1x=x$ and since they both equal $x$, we get $x^{x^2-2x}=2+\frac1x\iff x^{x^2-2x-1}=2+\frac1x$.

Are you meant to find a real solution, or prove you've found every real solution?

@J.G. not sure, I assumed some real solution existed and it was a ingle one

Given that this is a "brain teaser", you might suspect that there's going to be at most quadratic equations to solve.
Next notice that if $x^2 - 2 x + 1 = 2$, $x^2 = 2 x + 1$.
The solutions of $x^2 - 2 x + 1 = 2$ are $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$.

right but this assumes you know $x^2 - 2x +1 =2$ already, no? I wanted to try and see if there is some way to get there...

I didn't know it, but it's a good guess because it's one value of $n$ where $x^n = 2x + 1$ can be solved by hand.  There aren't a lot of others.

Alpha doesn't find an algebraic solution, and neither did I, but the numeric answer it gets looks a lot like $1+\sqrt 2$  If we rewrite your equation as $$x^{(x-1)^2}=2x+1$$
we can plug into the left hand side to get
$$(1+\sqrt 2)^{\sqrt 2 ^2}=(1+\sqrt 2)^2=3+2\sqrt 2=2(1+\sqrt 2)+1$$

Yeah, I can see that $(x-1)^2$ is supposed to be 2, once I rearrange it as $x^{(x-1)^2}-2x + 1 = 0$, but I was trying to see if there is a way to prove it more definitively? At least via "usual" precalc algebra.

This proves it definitively and uses no more than precalc algebra.  It doesn't explain how to find the solution of $1+\sqrt 2$ but it does verify that it works.

Right, I figured there has to be some way to find that solution, and it just bothers my sense of order, I guess, that there isn't an algebraic one? :-)
